# Derivative of vector wrt vector. How to place variables?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have an equation

$\mathbf{x_n} y_n - \mathbf{x_n}\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw})$

where $\mathbf{x_n}, \mathbf{w}$ are vectors, $y_n$ is a scalar and $\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw}) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\mathbf{x_n^Tw}}}$

What is its derivative wrt $\mathbf{w}$ ?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial w} (\mathbf{x_n} y_n - \mathbf{x_n}\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw}))$

The solution states

$ \mathbf{x_n}\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw})(1-\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw}))\mathbf{x_n^T}$

I know that

$\frac{\partial\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw})}{\partial x} = \sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw})(1-\sigma(\mathbf{x_n^Tw}))$

and that a derivative of a vector wrt a vector is a matrix but how do I know where to place $\mathbf{x_n^T}$. This is a simpler problem but what if I have a very long  equation ? I need to know how $\mathbf{x_n^T}$ is placed

Comment: Is your equation $$ \sum_{n=1}^N \left( x_ny_n - x_n\sigma(x_n^Tw) \right) $$ or  $$ \sum_{n=1}^N \left( x_ny_n \right) -  x_n\sigma(x_n^Tw)  $$ If the first one is valid ,there is no need to show the sum, and if the second one is true, then how is $n$ defined?

Comment: Sorry its the first one. I have edited my post

Comment: It might be better to reformat, using boldface for vectors and skipping the sum. You want the derivative of $$ \left( y_n  - \sigma( \mathbf{x}_n^\top \mathbf{w} ) \right) \mathbf{x}_n $$

Also, is $\mathbf{w}$ constant, or variable?

Comment: I think you meant $\frac{d\sigma(x)}{dx} =  \sigma(x)(\sigma(x)-1)$. At least that is what comes out of the definition for $\sigma(x)$.

Comment: sorry i have edited my post and fixed the error for $\sigma(x)$

Answer (score 1):

The subscripts are just visual clutter, so let's drop them and 
define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 x &= x_n,\,\,\,\lambda = y_n \cr
 \beta  &= x^Tw &\implies d\beta = x^T\,dw \cr
 \sigma &= \sigma(\beta) &\implies d\sigma = \sigma(1-\sigma)\,d\beta \cr
}$$ where I've used the convention where 
uppercase latin letters are matrices, 
lowercase latin letters are vectors, 
and greek letters are scalars.

Now the function of interest is 
$$\eqalign{ z &= x\,(\lambda - \sigma) }$$
Let's find its differential and Jacobian
$$\eqalign{
dz &= -x\,d\sigma \cr
   &= \sigma(\sigma-1)\,x\,d\beta \cr
   &= \sigma(\sigma-1)\,xx^T\,dw \cr
J = \frac{\partial z}{\partial w} &= \sigma(\sigma-1)\,xx^T \cr
}$$